# Как сделать, чтобы вместо первого блока .eq(0) выбирался случайный блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как сделать чтобы в Вашем скрипте заместо первого блока `.eq(0)` выбирался случайный блок, а потом всё шло по порядку?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text .text-block').eq(0).addClass("active").fadeIn(1000); // Показываем первый блок, можно и не первый, если прописать нужную цифру в eq()
    setInterval('blockAnimate();', 5000); // Вызываем функцию для смены блока каждые 5 секунд
});

// Функция для смены блоков, показывает блоки по очереди, начальный блок задаётся выше
function blockAnimate() {
    var length = $('.text .text-block').length - 1;
    $('.text .text-block').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active') && index != length) {
            $(this).removeClass("active").fadeOut(1000).next('.text-block').addClass("active").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        } else if (index == length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000);
            $('.text .text-block').eq(0).addClass("active").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: нужно заменить `0` на число получаемое случайно, например с использованием [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 2):

```
random=Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text .text-block').eq(random).addClass("active").fadeIn(1000); 
    setInterval('blockAnimate();', 5000); 
});
```

Где `min`- 0  а `max`- количество ваших элементов.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю!;)

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо ещё раз!)